# AWS CDK Code pipeline how to deploy to Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: aws-cdk

Trying to create a code pipeline for a Elastic Beanstalk environment with AWS CDK,
I have trouble creating the deploy stage.

In the AWS console I'm able to add an Action with an 'AWS Elastic Beanstalk' Action provider. I cannot find such a provider in the CDK.

Is there an other way or workaround to deploy to Elastic Beanstalk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the deploy to Elastic Beanstalk Action is not implemented I created the action using this class and interface:

```
import { ActionCategory, Action, Artifact } from "@aws-cdk/aws-codepipeline";

export interface ElasticBeanstalkDeployActionProps {
  ebsApplicationName: string;
  ebsEnvironmentName: string;
  input: Artifact;
}

export class ElasticBeanstalkDeployAction extends Action {
  constructor(props: ElasticBeanstalkDeployActionProps) {
    super({
      ...props,
      category: ActionCategory.Deploy,
      actionName: 'elasticbeanstalk-deploy-action',
      owner: 'AWS',
      provider: 'ElasticBeanstalk',
      artifactBounds: {
        minInputs: 1,
        maxInputs: 1,
        minOutputs: 0,
        maxOutputs: 0,
      },
      inputs: [props.input],
      configuration: {
        ApplicationName: props.ebsApplicationName,
        EnvironmentName: props.ebsEnvironmentName,
      },
    });
  }
  bind(_info: any) {
    // nothing to do
  }
}
```

To get the deploy working I had to attach the AWS managed policy `AWSElasticBeanstalkFullAccess` to the pipeline role

Comment: Hi Arjan I was able to create EB environment using my CDK code but in deploy step I am getting below error -
Insufficient permissions
The provided role does not have the elasticbeanstalk:CreateApplicationVersion permission

and I don't know how to assign - AWSElasticBeanstalkFullAccess  policy using cdk .
Could you please help me here

Comment: @Dhirah :

const pipeline: Pipeline = new Pipeline(this.scope, pipelineName, {
            artifactBucket,
            pipelineName,
            restartExecutionOnUpdate: false,
        });

        pipeline.role.attachManagedPolicy('arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSElasticBeanstalkFullAccess');

(sorry for the lack of formatting)

Comment: Thanks for the response I have got this resolved. :)

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is still an open issue in the CDK and tracked here:

https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cdk/issues/2516

I am not aware of a workaround.